# Track internal javascript links

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onclick

I'd like to track clicks on links that already have javascript onclick event. I'm using analytics but I have no idea how to track these clicks with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track it with custom message, to distinguish local from others:

```
 $('.local-link').click(function () {
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Local link', 'click', 'some extra message here']);
 });
```

You can read more about google custom events on google page http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

You can call multiple functions with one OnClick event:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']); foobar();"
```

Or you can attach event tracking to other JS actions, like OnMouseDown or OnMouseUp.